# Azure Gateway WAF - Diagnostics Issue

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-application-gateway, azure-security, azure-waf

I'm trying to setup Azure WAF (v2) on my App Gateway (currently in detection mode first to handle false positive cases), however, I'm seeing this warning:

```
To view your detection logs, you must have diagnostics enabled.
```

So, I went to `Diagnostic settings` and created it there with following options:

Log:

`ApplicationGatewayAccessLog` - (checked)

`ApplicationGatewayPerformanceLog` - (checked)

`ApplicationGatewayFirewallLog` - (checked)

Metric:

`AllMetrics` - (checked)

I have `Send to Log Analytics` checked as well. Also `Archive to a storage account` enabled.

But I'm still seeing the same warning mentioned above. 
Any idea what I might be missing here?

UPDATE, I do see records within log with following query, but warning is still there:

```
AzureDiagnostics | where OperationName == "ApplicationGatewayFirewall"
```

Comment: Just to make sure, if you refresh the diagnostic settings blade, you do see your configuration. Right? Maybe logging on and off? We do use App Gateway w/WAF enabled and did not face this behaviour.

Comment: I do see it under App Gateway \ Diagnostic Settings, and I tried to log out and log in again, but still same warning. I even tried to run some malicious scan to make sure that I will have some logs, but still no luck.

Comment: Go to your log analytics / logs and look for ApplicationGatewayFirewall. Is there any data?

Comment: @LMG I have updated my question, I did run a query as you suggested, and I see my requests when I go trough log analytics workspace, however, warning is still there.

Comment: @ShP The same issue is happening for me as well. I'm wondering if you found a solution for it?

Comment: @Matrix if you are asking about logs, it takes a min to show logs under AzureDiagnostics. If you were referring to the warning, it's been a while since I did this, but I think it was related to what I had selected for diagnostic, check this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/firewall-diagnostics Also one additional note if you are just starting with WAF, might be a better option to use WAF for Azure FrontDoor instead of WAF for AppGateway. It gives a bit more options (e.g. geofence etc.).

Comment: Thanks :) I can see the logs now however the warning is still there. I have to use WAF on appgw as it is the only way to integrate it to AKS that we use for the applications.